# Get items which contain any of the strings in a Collection

Tags: c#, linq

What I have right now is this:

```
var dividendItemsRecord = yearItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Record"));
var dividendItemsPayable = yearItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Payable"));
var dividendItemsCash = yearItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Cash"));

var dividendItems = dividendItemsRecord.Concat(dividendItemsPayable)
                                        .Concat(dividendItemsCash)
                                        .ToList();
```

This is clearly not the way I would like to do it, I am wondering if anybody knows a way to do it in one step.

PS: The items found will never intersect

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("a") || x.Name.Contains("b"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join multiple conditions in one, with logical **OR** statement:

```
var dividend = yearItem.GetType().GetProperties().
Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Record") || x.Name.Contains("Payable") || x.Name.Contains("Cash"));
```

Comment: @Ilya.N. Don't forget the ToList() if you don't want an enumeration!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it :

```
var listOfItems = yearItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Record") || x => x.Name.Contains("Payable") || x => x.Name.Contains("Cash")).ToList();
```